# Does the constant on an LFSR primitive polynomial hold any significance?

Tags: shift-register

For the following internal feedback LFSR defined by the primitive polynomial: $$X^3 + X + 1$$ Does the constant at the end do anything to either its pseudo-random number generation sequence or to its structure? For example, if the constant at the end was a zero?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you remove the path labelled \$1x^0\$ in your diagram?

Comment: That would be a major structural change and the output sequence would make the maximum number of output variations reduced from 7 to 3. The only reason I ask is that every example online has +1 tagged on the end.

Comment: You just answered your own question

Comment: Here's a question for you: what is x to the power 0?

Comment: One. Yeah that is true - just it is never mentioned. So I can assume for an LFSR, there is always +1 in the polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments clarified. X to the power of 0 is always 1 - so for a primitive polynomial, there is *always* a +1 attached.